# how can i read a character if I have the initial pointer of that string

Tags: c

I have the initial pointer of the string how can read the value in character array from that string.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char *str="A C string";
printf("The first character is %c\n",*str);
printf("The second character is %c\n",*(str+1));
```

Comment: `printf("The first character is %c\n",str[0]);` `printf("The second character is %c\n",str[1]);` just for completeness ;-)

Comment: Please add a `const` and a `;` to your declaration.